# A question on enumerative combinatorics : k-length subsequence of n-length sequence

Tags: combinatorics

Is this a known result?

Let $A = (a_1,...,a_n)$ be a sequence of $n$ integers such that $a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_n$. We say a permutation $\sigma$ is $k$-safe if in $\sigma$, no $k+1$ length subsequence from the original sequence $A$ is preserved but at-least one $k$ length subsequence is preserved. How many $k$-safe permutations are there for $A$.

Note: a subsequence need not be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for oeis that answers this:
https://oeis.org/A047874